# Question about proof of Stone-Weierstrass

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

I would like to know if I understand the details in the proof of Stone-Weierstrass (in $\mathbb R$) so I'd like to post it here in my own words. Can you please check it and tell me if it's correct? Thank you!

Thm. (Stone-Weierstrass) Let $A$ be a unital subalgebra of $(C(K),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ that separates points, where $K$ is a compact topological space and $C(K)$ are continuous functions $K \to \mathbb R$. Then $\overline{A} = C(K)$.

Proof: We use (without proof) that

(i) if $A$ is a subalgebra then so is $\overline{A}$

(ii) if $f,g$ in $\overline{A}$ then $\min (f,g)$ and $\max(f,g)$ are in $\overline{A}$

Let $f \in C(K)$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. We construct $h \in \overline{A}$ such that $h(x) - \varepsilon \leq f(x) \leq h(x) + \varepsilon$.

To this end let $x_0 \in K$ be fixed. Then since $\overline{A}$ separates points, for each $x \in K$ we can find $h_x \in \overline{A}$ such that $h_x(x_0) = f(x_0)$ and $h_x(x) = f(x)$. 
Since $h_x - f$ is continuous and $h_x(x) = f(x)$ there are $O_x$ open such that for $x^\prime \in O_x$ we have $|(h_x -f)(x) - (h_x -f)(x^\prime)| = |h_x(x^\prime) - f(x^\prime)| < \varepsilon $. In particular, $h_x(x^\prime)  - \varepsilon\leq f(x^\prime) $ for all $x^\prime \in O_x$.
Since $K$ is compact and $O_x$ cover $K$ there is a finite subcover $\{O_{x_i} \}_{i=1}^N$. Let $h_{x_0} (x) : = \min_i h_{x_i} (x)$. Then for all $x \in K$ we have  $h_{x_0}(x) - \varepsilon \leq f(x) $.

$h_{x_0}$ is continuous and $h_{x_0}(x_0) = f(x_0)$ hence for each $x_0 \in K$ there is $U_{x_0}$ open such that for $x^\prime \in U_{x_0}$ we have $|(h_{x_0} -f)(x^\prime) - (h_{x_0} -f)(x_0)| = |h_{x_0}(x^\prime) - f(x^\prime)| < \varepsilon$. In particular, $f(x^\prime) \leq h_{x_0}(x^\prime)+\varepsilon$. Since $U_{x_0}$ are open and cover $K$ there is a finite subcover $\{U_{x_i} \}_{i=1}^M$. Let $h(x) = \max_i h_{x_i}(x)$ then $h(x) \in \overline{A}$ and $h(x) - \varepsilon \leq f(x) \leq h(x) + \varepsilon$. Let $\varepsilon \to 0$.

Comment: In the last line, shouldn't $h(x)$ be $\min_ih_{x_i}(x)$?

Comment: @SamL. I need to show $f \in \overline{A}$. Letting $\varepsilon \to 0$ gives me $f = h \in \overline{A}$ which is what I wanted to show. No?

Comment: @AneeshkarthikC No, we have $f(x^\prime) \leq h_{x_i}(x^\prime)+\varepsilon$ for all $i$ so we want to take the $\max$ over all $i$ to ensure that $f(x) \leq h(x) + \varepsilon$.

Comment: @SamL. But is it mathematically correct like this?

Comment: I think in (ii) you need $A$ to be closed?

Comment: @joriki Thank you! You are right, that was a typo (not a thinko : )).

Comment: @joriki Is "$\varepsilon \to 0$" at the end mathematically correct? (unfortunately the comment by Sam L. has been removed).

Comment: This "Let $\varepsilon \to 0$." Makes very little sense. You *fixed* $\varepsilon \gt 0$ (and $f$) at the beginning of the proof, now you can't just let it go to zero. The idea is that you show that for every $f$ and every $\varepsilon \gt 0$ you can find $h \in \overline{A} \cap B_\varepsilon(f)$, which implies that $\overline{A}$ is dense, but as it is also closed, it must be everything.

Comment: @t.b. I made a thinko there. I thought that $\varepsilon$ was fixed but arbitrary so while $f$ stays the same I can redo the argument for $\varepsilon/2, \varepsilon/4, \dots $ etc. Of course this does not work because $h$ is really $h_\varepsilon$. (Btw: Yay you're here! And hi. Was sad because I thought you might've vanished.)

Comment: Of course you can do that, and you'd get a sequence $h_{\varepsilon_n}$ converging to $f$ in the uniform norm so not that bad a thinko (re: btw, I haven't vanished, I just try not to waste too much time here and I'm quite successful so far).